# How to match specific Unix shell-style strings using Python's fnmatch?

Tags: python, regex, fnmatch

I would like to create a Unix shell-style pattern that will only match strings with specific suffixes. The pattern in question starts with `0.1` and can finish with `test` or `alpha` or `.` .

This means that `0.1test` and `0.1alpha` should match but not `0.1beta` or `0-1alpha`.
I've constructed the following patterns:

1. `0.1{.,test,alpha}`
2. `0.1{["."],["test"],["alpha"]}`

but both fail when tested as such:

```
import fnmatch
result = fnmatch.fnmatch(v, glob_pattern)
if result:
    print('SUCCESS')
else:
    print('FAILURE')
```

Comment: What are the test cases you check on?

Comment: They're included in the post's description. They are `0.1test`, `0.1alpha` , `0.1beta` and `0-1alpha`.

Answer (score 2):

The `fnmatch.fnmatch` function does not support curly braces in the glob pattern.

Instead, you can install the [`braceexpand`](https://pypi.org/project/braceexpand/) module to expand a pattern with curly braces into all possible strings that the pattern represents, so that each of them can then be passed to `fnmatch.fnmatch` for a match:

```
from fnmatch import fnmatch
from braceexpand import braceexpand

def brace_fnmatch(name, pattern):
    return any(fnmatch(name, p) for p in braceexpand(pattern))
```

so that:

```
for name in '0.1test', '0.1alpha', '0.1beta', '0-1alpha':
    print(name, end=' ')
    if brace_fnmatch(name, '0.1{.,test,alpha}'):
        print('matches')
    else:
        print('does not match')
```

outputs:

```
0.1test matches
0.1alpha matches
0.1beta does not match
0-1alpha does not match
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing1/ColorfulCornsilkGigabyte